# Allow hover menu to overlap/break-out of scrollable parent container

Tags: html, css

I have a scrollable table with the far-right column containing a hover menu.  This has been achieved so far by placing the table inside a container and restricting the width/height to trigger scroll bars when the table grows larger.

The challenge is that because the hover-menu is also inside the scrollable container, at times it doesn't correctly appear:

[image]

I understand that this is exactly what `overflow: scroll` is *supposed* to achieve, but I'm wondering whether there is alternative functionality to allow the hover menu to "break out" of its parent container(s) without using JavaScript-based positioning?

[SCSS-based CodePen](https://codepen.io/evildr/pen/wvZaNed)

From research so far it appears I need to either:

- Lose the kebab menu, or
- Add lots of padding-bottom to the container, or
- Lose the scroll functionality

...but I'm hoping there's a way to avoid the above.

### Update

Further to Tim's comments an issue has now developed using `position: fixed` on the menu. When the table's container has scrollbars and is scrolled, the position of each row's respective menu appears exponentially downwards (e.g. the fourth row is four times the vertical height downwards to what it should be).

The following shows what happens when the final row's menu is activated:

##### Table container has no scrollbars/scrolling

Menu appears correctly:

[image]

##### Table container has scrollbars and is scrolled

Menu appears exponentially lower than it's respective row (note - padding added to body so menu shows *somewhere*, and container's max-height reduced to simulate the issue):

[Latest CodePen](https://codepen.io/evildr/pen/oNOXRpN)

[image]

```css
.SearchResultsGridContainer {
  padding: 1rem;
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  background-color: #fee;
}
.SearchResultsGridContainer .SearchResultsGrid {
  max-height: 70vh;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
  padding: 0 0.5rem 1rem 0;
  background-color: #dcc;
}
.SearchResultsGridContainer .SearchResultsGrid table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.SearchResultsGridContainer .SearchResultsGrid table thead tr th {
  background-color: #aaa;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
}
.SearchResultsGridContainer .SearchResultsGrid table tbody tr td {
  padding: 1rem;
}
.SearchResultsGridContainer .SearchResultsGrid table tbody tr td.KebabMenu {
  border: 3px outset gray;
  text-align: center;
}
.SearchResultsGridContainer .SearchResultsGrid table tbody tr td.KebabMenu button {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
}
.SearchResultsGridContainer .SearchResultsGrid table tbody tr td.KebabMenu ul {
  display: none;
}
.SearchResultsGridContainer .SearchResultsGrid table tbody tr td.KebabMenu:hover {
  position: relative;
}
.SearchResultsGridContainer .SearchResultsGrid table tbody tr td.KebabMenu:hover ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  width: 10rem;
}
.SearchResultsGridContainer .SearchResultsGrid table tbody tr td.KebabMenu:hover ul li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.SearchResultsGridContainer .SearchResultsGrid table tbody tr td.KebabMenu:hover ul li a {
  display: block;
  white-space: no-wrap;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
.SearchResultsGridContainer .SearchResultsGrid table tbody tr td.KebabMenu:hover ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #eef;
}
```

```html
<div class="SearchResultsGridContainer">
    <div class="SearchResultsGrid">
        <table role="table">
            <thead role="rowgroup">
                <tr>
                    <th role="columnheader">
                        Column header 01
                    </th>
                    <th role="columnheader">
                        Column header 02
                    </th>
                    <th role="columnheader">
                        Column header 03
                    </th>
                    <th role="columnheader">
                        Column header 04
                    </th>
                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody role="rowgroup">
                <tr role="row">
                    <td>Row 01 Column 01</td>
                    <td>Row 01 Column 02</td>
                    <td>Row 01 Column 03</td>
                    <td>Row 01 Column 04</td>
                    <td class="KebabMenu">...
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 01</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 02</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 03</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 04</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr role="row">
                    <td>Row 02 Column 01</td>
                    <td>Row 02 Column 02</td>
                    <td>Row 02 Column 03</td>
                    <td>Row 02 Column 04</td>
                    <td class="KebabMenu">...
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 01</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 02</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 03</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 04</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr role="row">
                    <td>Row 03 Column 01</td>
                    <td>Row 03 Column 02</td>
                    <td>Row 03 Column 03</td>
                    <td>Row 03 Column 04</td>
                    <td class="KebabMenu">...
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 01</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 02</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 03</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 04</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr role="row">
                    <td>Row 04 Column 01</td>
                    <td>Row 04 Column 02</td>
                    <td>Row 04 Column 03</td>
                    <td>Row 04 Column 04</td>
                    <td class="KebabMenu">
                        ...
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 01</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 02</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 03</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 04</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `position:fixed` on the `ul` and removing top/right/bottom/left gets me pretty close (and it's a good scenario to use `fixed`).

Comment: Nice, thank you!  By also adding `transform: translate(-90%)` to pull it back over the table I think it's there, but aren't sure if there are any gotchas that exist with this ([see forked CodePen](https://codepen.io/evildr/pen/oNOXRpN?editors=1100)) - other than the obvious translate matching the width of the `ul`.  Might need to implement it into the project properly and keep an eye on things then report back...

Comment: There's an issue sadly.  I've updated the question to clarify the finding.

Comment: _"without using JavaScript-based positioning?"_ - not sure if that is really possible, "popular" articles about scenarios like this, such as https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/, use JS to "fix" the positioning.

Comment: @CBroe yes I'm being led to think it's the solution.  I'd seen that article but was hoping that because its quite old now, that CSS3 might have delivered some "magic workaround"...!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my experiment. Not perfect and I am not sure how helpful it will be. Maybe it could lead to a better solution.

Basically, I am manipulating the value of `top` through `ul:nth-child` so that the `ul` remains inside the table.

Edit: Reducing the padding a bit, now it looks perfect.

```css
.SearchResultsGridContainer {
  padding: 1rem;
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  background-color: #fee;
}
.SearchResultsGridContainer .SearchResultsGrid {
  max-height: 70vh;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
  padding: 0 0.5rem 1rem 0;
  background-color: #dcc;
}
.SearchResultsGridContainer .SearchResultsGrid table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.SearchResultsGridContainer .SearchResultsGrid table thead tr th {
  background-color: #aaa;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
}
.SearchResultsGridContainer .SearchResultsGrid table tbody tr td {
  padding: 1rem;
}
.SearchResultsGridContainer .SearchResultsGrid table tbody tr td.KebabMenu {
  border: 3px outset gray;
  text-align: center;
}
.SearchResultsGridContainer .SearchResultsGrid table tbody tr td.KebabMenu button {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
}
.SearchResultsGridContainer .SearchResultsGrid table tbody tr td.KebabMenu ul {
  display: none;
}
.SearchResultsGridContainer .SearchResultsGrid table tbody tr td.KebabMenu:hover {
  position: relative;
}
.SearchResultsGridContainer .SearchResultsGrid table tbody tr td.KebabMenu:hover ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  width: 10rem;
}
ul:nth-child(-n+1){
    top: -60px !important;
}

.SearchResultsGridContainer .SearchResultsGrid table tbody tr td.KebabMenu:hover ul li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.SearchResultsGridContainer .SearchResultsGrid table tbody tr td.KebabMenu:hover ul li a {
  display: block;
  white-space: no-wrap;
  padding: 0.3rem;
}
.SearchResultsGridContainer .SearchResultsGrid table tbody tr td.KebabMenu:hover ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #eef;
}
```

```html
<div class="SearchResultsGridContainer">
    <div class="SearchResultsGrid">
        <table role="table">
            <thead role="rowgroup">
                <tr>
                    <th role="columnheader">
                        Column header 01
                    </th>
                    <th role="columnheader">
                        Column header 02
                    </th>
                    <th role="columnheader">
                        Column header 03
                    </th>
                    <th role="columnheader">
                        Column header 04
                    </th>
                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody role="rowgroup">
                <tr role="row">
                    <td>Row 01 Column 01</td>
                    <td>Row 01 Column 02</td>
                    <td>Row 01 Column 03</td>
                    <td>Row 01 Column 04</td>
                    <td class="KebabMenu">...
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 01</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 02</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 03</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 04</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr role="row">
                    <td>Row 02 Column 01</td>
                    <td>Row 02 Column 02</td>
                    <td>Row 02 Column 03</td>
                    <td>Row 02 Column 04</td>
                    <td class="KebabMenu">...
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 01</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 02</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 03</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 04</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr role="row">
                    <td>Row 03 Column 01</td>
                    <td>Row 03 Column 02</td>
                    <td>Row 03 Column 03</td>
                    <td>Row 03 Column 04</td>
                    <td class="KebabMenu">...
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 01</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 02</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 03</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 04</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr role="row">
                    <td>Row 02 Column 01</td>
                    <td>Row 02 Column 02</td>
                    <td>Row 02 Column 03</td>
                    <td>Row 02 Column 04</td>
                    <td class="KebabMenu">...
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 01</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 02</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 03</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 04</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr role="row">
                    <td>Row 03 Column 01</td>
                    <td>Row 03 Column 02</td>
                    <td>Row 03 Column 03</td>
                    <td>Row 03 Column 04</td>
                    <td class="KebabMenu">...
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 01</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 02</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 03</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 04</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr role="row">
                    <td>Row 02 Column 01</td>
                    <td>Row 02 Column 02</td>
                    <td>Row 02 Column 03</td>
                    <td>Row 02 Column 04</td>
                    <td class="KebabMenu">...
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 01</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 02</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 03</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 04</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr role="row">
                    <td>Row 03 Column 01</td>
                    <td>Row 03 Column 02</td>
                    <td>Row 03 Column 03</td>
                    <td>Row 03 Column 04</td>
                    <td class="KebabMenu">...
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 01</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 02</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 03</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 04</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr role="row">
                    <td>Row 02 Column 01</td>
                    <td>Row 02 Column 02</td>
                    <td>Row 02 Column 03</td>
                    <td>Row 02 Column 04</td>
                    <td class="KebabMenu">...
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 01</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 02</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 03</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 04</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr role="row">
                    <td>Row 03 Column 01</td>
                    <td>Row 03 Column 02</td>
                    <td>Row 03 Column 03</td>
                    <td>Row 03 Column 04</td>
                    <td class="KebabMenu">...
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 01</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 02</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 03</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 04</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr role="row">
                    <td>Row 02 Column 01</td>
                    <td>Row 02 Column 02</td>
                    <td>Row 02 Column 03</td>
                    <td>Row 02 Column 04</td>
                    <td class="KebabMenu">...
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 01</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 02</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 03</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 04</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr role="row">
                    <td>Row 03 Column 01</td>
                    <td>Row 03 Column 02</td>
                    <td>Row 03 Column 03</td>
                    <td>Row 03 Column 04</td>
                    <td class="KebabMenu">...
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 01</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 02</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 03</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 04</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr role="row">
                    <td>Row 02 Column 01</td>
                    <td>Row 02 Column 02</td>
                    <td>Row 02 Column 03</td>
                    <td>Row 02 Column 04</td>
                    <td class="KebabMenu">...
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 01</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 02</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 03</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 04</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr role="row">
                    <td>Row 03 Column 01</td>
                    <td>Row 03 Column 02</td>
                    <td>Row 03 Column 03</td>
                    <td>Row 03 Column 04</td>
                    <td class="KebabMenu">...
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 01</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 02</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 03</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 04</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr role="row">
                    <td>Row 04 Column 01</td>
                    <td>Row 04 Column 02</td>
                    <td>Row 04 Column 03</td>
                    <td>Row 04 Column 04</td>
                    <td class="KebabMenu">
                        ...
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 01</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 02</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 03</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 04</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look.  When viewed full-screen but on a shrunken window the hover menu hides at the top.  However you nth-child approach has given me an idea whereby perhaps a different positioning rule can be applied for the latter row menus...

Comment: @EvilDr You are right, but the amount of shrink it takes to make it hide at the top is quite a lot, you have to block almost the whole window. No one is going to use their browser like that.

Comment: @EvilDr Please let me know if you find any other workaround.